# Como efetuar uma operação aritmética sem ordená-la no GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tendo o seguinte SELECT consultando uma tabela dinâmica à partir de um subselect, eu obtenho o resultado da consulta corretamente porém com registros divididos no seguinte exemplo:

```
cod_representante | ... | VALOR_TOTAL_MERCEARIA | VALOR_TOTAL_PC_MP
 123              | ... | 59000                 | 0
 123              | ... | 0                     | 2000
```

Quando deveria agrupá-lo somente pelo `cod_representante`:

```
cod_representante | ... | VALOR_TOTAL_MERCEARIA | VALOR_TOTAL_PC_MP
123             | ... | 59000                 | 2000
```

O Select:

```
SELECT codFunc,
       regional AS gerente,
       nome_gerente AS supervisor,
       cod_representante,
       nome_representante,
       SUM(valor_total_seca) AS VALOR_TOTAL_MERCEARIA,
       SUM(valor_total_liquida) AS VALOR_TOTAL_PC_MP,
       
       ISNULL(valor_total_seca,0) + ISNULL(valor_total_liquida,0) AS TOTAL_GERAL,
       ISNULL(valor_rateio,0) AS VALOR_DAS_DEVOLUCOES,
       CASE
           WHEN valor_rateio IS NULL THEN (ISNULL(valor_total_seca,0) + ISNULL(valor_total_liquida,0))
           ELSE (ISNULL(valor_total_seca,0) + ISNULL(valor_total_liquida,0)) - ISNULL(valor_rateio,0)
       END AS TOTAL_SEM_DEV,
       ISNULL(comissao, 0) AS PERCENTUAL_COMISSAO,
       ((ISNULL(valor_total_seca,0) + ISNULL(valor_total_liquida,0)) - ISNULL(valor_rateio,0)) * ISNULL(comissao,0) AS VALOR_DA_COMISSAO
FROM ...
```

O GROUP BY:

```
GROUP BY regional,
         cod_gerente,
         nome_gerente,
         cod_representante,
         codFunc,
         nome_representante,
         valor_total_seca ,
         valor_total_liquida,
         valor_rateio,
         comissao
```

Caso eu não inclua os campos que estão sendo manipulados na operação aritmética, no trecho abaixo,

```
ISNULL(valor_total_seca,0) + ISNULL(valor_total_liquida,0) AS TOTAL_GERAL,
           ISNULL(valor_rateio,0) AS VALOR_DAS_DEVOLUCOES,
           CASE
               WHEN valor_rateio IS NULL THEN (ISNULL(valor_total_seca,0) + ISNULL(valor_total_liquida,0))
               ELSE (ISNULL(valor_total_seca,0) + ISNULL(valor_total_liquida,0)) - ISNULL(valor_rateio,0)
           END AS TOTAL_SEM_DEV,
           ISNULL(comissao, 0) AS PERCENTUAL_COMISSAO,
           ((ISNULL(valor_total_seca,0) + ISNULL(valor_total_liquida,0)) - ISNULL(valor_rateio,0)) * ISNULL(comissao,0) AS VALOR_DA_COMISSAO
```

eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 13 Column 't.valor_total_seca' is
> invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
> aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 13 Column 't.valor_total_liquida' is invalid in the select
> list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or
> the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer um select fora de tudo com os campos agrupados. Sem ver o SLQ inteiro não vou conseguir garantir 100%, mas essa seria uma solução:

```
SELECT cod_representante ,
       count(VALOR_TOTAL_MERCEARIA),
       count(VALOR_TOTAL_PC_MP)
FROM (
  --todo o seu sql atual
)
gropy by cod_representante
```

Esse novo SQL vai executar bem rápido porque vai pegar somente os registros retornados do seu atual.

**ATUALIZANDO**

Eu cheguei a excluir a resposta porque não gostei da minha solução, mas olhando uma segunda vez o problema eu acho que isso está acontecendo porque você usa essas colunas em duas colunas no SQL, acho que uma solução como essa que eu dei até facilitaria a leitura do SQL.

Comment: Ricardo, utilizando a solução proposta até funciona caso eu só pegue essas colunas, porém preciso exibir todas as colunas do primeiro SELECT mostrado. Consequentemente eu sou obrigado a agrupá-los novamente pelo SQL e os valores terminam sendo separados como antes.

Comment: Mas aí vc agrupa todas, menos as duas, desde que no select tenham o sum neles ele vai agrupar, não vai?

Comment: Com algumas alterações, houve uma breve solução.